# One Form with Fields from two Tables

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2007

I am very new to Access 2007 and am trying to create one form which has multiple tabs on it.  Four of the tabs represent information from one table and two of the tabs represent information from a second table.

There is a relationship between the two tables:  Enrollment Table!ID has a lookup relationship to Medical Info!ID Lookup.

If there is a new record created using the form, which automatically assignes and ID to the client record in the Enrollment Table, I would like the a corresponding record to be automaticaly created in the Medical Info table.

The problem I am having is that if I create a new client with the form, and move to the medical info table on the form, I can successfully display the ID Lookup results, however, no record is created in the medical info table unless I enter data into one field first.

If this makes sense, is there a way to write the record to the Medical Info Table at the point that the Client ID is created, which would establish the relationship between "Client ID" and "ID Lookup" without having to enter into another field first?

Comment: I would say this issue is not related to database design. It has to do with Access Forms functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too deep into your Db or form, I'd venture a guess at doing what you need like so:

In your form, at the point of entry of the Client ID, use the (after_update) trigger to check to see if it is a new record or not, and to  run an insert SQL to the medical info table and requery the form or to requery the form's fields that use data from the first table.  You could use some entry  such as "new enrollment" in a field that likely has information on the medical activity done in a typical entry, and even today's date for the activity date.

Or , you could create a button to do so instead of the after_update.

Either case, you'll need to do some data validating to make sure it will not cause errors in the insert query.

Post some more specifics if this isn't enough help.